# Revit API - How to set the north orientation when creating a View3D?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm trying to find a way to set the north orientation of a View3D. Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong part here but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

Any help on this would be awesome!

Comment: I am not an expert on setting up Revit, but I do indeed believe you might be looking at the wrong part. One thing is certain: your best bet is to research how to address this properly manually in the user interface before you start thinking about any programmatic aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Project North is a project setting which is the same as True North unless it is rotated differently in a 2D view.  If you rotate project north in a 2D view I think it will update in all views including 3D views.

Answer (score 0):

if you meant setting orientation of a 3d view then try this code:

```
View3D active3dView = _uiDoc.Document.ActiveView as View3D;
ViewOrientation3D viewOrientation3D = new ViewOrientation3D(eyePosition, upDirection, forwardDirection);
active3dView.SetOrientation(viewOrientation3D);
```

You need to specify 3 arguments first: eyePosition, upDirection, forwardDirection.